# Base conversion of a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, hex, string-conversion

I'm trying to succinctly convert the string **"eamorr"** to **"2018e8c"** in node.js

"eamorr" is in base32 and "2018e8c" is some sort of hex (I'm not sure).

Using code grabbed from http://jsfiddle.net/nt18yhmL/, here's how I'm currently doing it:

```
function base32tohex(base32) {
        var base32chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567";
        var bits = "";
        var hex = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < base32.length; i++) {
            var val = base32chars.indexOf(base32.charAt(i).toUpperCase());
            bits += leftpad(val.toString(2), 5, '0');
        }

        for (var i = 0; i+4 <= bits.length; i+=4) {
            var chunk = bits.substr(i, 4);
            hex = hex + parseInt(chunk, 2).toString(16) ;
        }
        return hex;
}
function leftpad(str, len, pad) {
        if (len + 1 >= str.length) {
                str = Array(len + 1 - str.length).join(pad) + str;
        }
        return str;
}
var key="eamorr"
console.log(base32tohex(key));    //prints the correct string (2018e8c)
```

This works fine for me. But surely there must be a more succinct way of doing this using just built-in functions?

Here's what I've tried:

```
var base32 = require('base32');
var buff = new Buffer(base32.decode("eamorr"),'utf8');
console.log(buff.toString('hex'));
```

This requires 'base32', and it prints out the wrong result **"72c2a80c"** ;(

Comment: There is not a single agreed-upon definition of what 'base32' actually is.  So the 3rd party module you have would need to agree with whatever your implementation is for encoding.

Comment: Also is your q right?  This converter: http://tomeko.net/online_tools/base32.php?lang=en says 'eamorr' is 2018e8 and not 2018e8c as you note.

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted "base 32" :)

Comment: @Pointy that's numerical bases.  Base32 as described here is something like RFC4648

Comment: @Joe yes I started to suspect I was doing something wrong :)

Comment: @Joe, yes, sorry; a typo on my part.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a generic radix(base) conversion library you would probably find useful. https://github.com/cflynn07/power-radix

In your example, you would use PowerRadix like this:

```
var PowerRadix = require('power-radix');
var base32Set = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567".split('');
var hexSet = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
// assuming you intended 'eamorr' to be 'EAMORR' since your 
// defined base32 character set only contains capital characters
new PowerRadix('EAMORR', base32Set)
  .toArray(hexSet); // [ 'C', 'D', '5', '5', '2', '1', '1']
new PowerRadix('EAMORR', base32Set)
  .toArray(hexSet); // 'CD55211'
```